# Android: Serializable Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an object that has (among other things) a list of Intents.  I want to pass this object as an extra to an Intent.  However, the Intent class is not serializable, it is just "Parcelable".

I assume that Parcelable is the android version of Serializable, but I'd rather not have to write my own serialization code for my class, and Parcelable seems to require that.

Anyone have any solutions to this other than just reimplementing the Intent as a serializable class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `Parcelable` in an `Intent` extra, and an `Intent` is already `Parcelable`. All you need to do is make your object `Parcelable` and you are set.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make your intent Parcelable?  Serializable is nice because you just have to throw the interface on, it looks like you have to manually serialize your object in parcelable..

Comment: Yes, I understand that Intents are, but my object is not, and it contains a number of somewhat complex objects.  Hand-creating serialization code seems error prone.

Comment: Since you cannot make an `Intent` implement `Serializable` without firmware modifications, your choices are either to implement `Parcelable` on your class or not pass instances of it via extras.

Answer (score 0):

Another Route you can take:

make your list of intents transient(not included in a serializable),
then pass it as a parcelable array via Intent.putExtra(String key, Parcelable[] value).

The receiving class can then recreate your Object.